# flyway doesn't create schema after initial schemas creations

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using flyway-core 7.15.0 and spring-boot 2.4.11. Here is the flyway configuration in the application.properties file

```
spring.flyway.schemas=schema1,schema2
spring.flyway.table=schema_version
spring.flyway.out-of-order=true
spring.flyway.ignore-missing-migrations=true
```

also, I have this bean

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationArguments appArgs;

@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() {
    return flyway -> {
        if (appArgs.containsOption("flywayClean")) {
            flyway.clean();
        }
        if (appArgs.containsOption("flywayRepair")) {
            flyway.repair();
        }
        flyway.migrate();
    };
}
```

Everything works fine but when I added one more schema like this and restarted the app that new schema doesn't create.

```
spring.flyway.schemas=schema1,schema2,schema3
```

Does anybody know why schema3 is not added which added after the first run?

Answer (score 0):

At the current version - 7.x, and the v8 betas - the check to create schemas is only done on a "clean" database - that is, the schema history table hasn't been created, Hence, if you've started a sequence of migrations and change the `schemas` parameter by adding an extra one, it never gets created. (Strictly, only if the `schemas` parameter hasn't changed in such a way as to change the implied location of the history table!)

I'll raise this as an issue with the team to review. https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3296

Comment: Thanks Julia Hayward, for your response. I Will follow the issue. 
In a code, I found that this part is added where it checks if does not exist the schema then creates but seems that it is added for another reason. 

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/5f01253088e21b5a30e817d831e7b32248285ae4/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/command/DbSchemas.java#L89